# How to increase the running time performance of Stanford Named Entity classifier?

Tags: performance, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using the Stanford Named Entity toolkit with social media streams. However using that huge number of documents/sentences, I need to enhance the running time performance of the recognizer/classifier. I was wondering what are some techniques that I could do in order to solve this problem.

I need to mention that I only need to recognize one class of entities, organization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would using a Stanford Named Entity model with one class increase running time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790322/would-using-a-stanford-named-entity-model-with-one-class-increase-running-time)

Answer (score 0):

`corenlp.sh` takes a `threads` parameter

Comment: but I want to use it programmatically not as a shell script.

Comment: call the unix command from whichever language you're using, that way you save the trouble of reading into Stanford's code.